# How to pass a variable in the View method in Laravel

Tags: laravel, view, subdomain

how do I pass a variable that can be parsed by the view() method in Laravel?

```
  public function index($department_id) { 

     $employees=Employee::all();  
     $department=Department::find($department_id); 

     return view('departments.$department->department_code.index')->with('department',$department)->with('employees', $employees); 
  }
```

The idea is that every department has a department folder with the same name as the department_code from the department model. I want to be able to receive the department_id, retrieve the correct department and then return the appropriate view with all the attributes of the department.

I get this error `InvalidArgumentException
View [departments.$department->department_code.index] not found.` when I tried to do it this way.

Answer (score 2):

```
return view(sprintf('departments.%s.index', $department->department_code), [
    'departments' => $departments,
    'employees' => $employees,
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use inline variables in a string, you need to use double quotes (`"`).

```
return view("departments.$department->department_code.index")->with('department',$department)->with('employees', $employees);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
return view("departments.$department->department_code.index", compact('employees','department'))
```